# Show span if parent div hasClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm beating myself over the head with this one. I don't know what's doing on. It's pretty simple but it just doesn't work. I want to show a `span` item when a `div` has a `class`. Yup, basic, but I can't get it to work.

Here is my HTML with the class `add-product`

```
<div id="ot-pr" class="status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry add-product">
    <span class="arrow">Testing</span>
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    if ($("#ot-pr").hasClass('add-product')){
        $(".arrow").show();
    } else { 
        $(".arrow").hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the CSS of the `.arrow`

```
.arrow {
    display: none;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #c8c8c8;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

What have I tried, adding a `find(span)` and add `else if`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#ot-pr").hasClass('add-product')){
        $(".arrow").find('span').show();
    } else if { 
        $(".arrow").hide();
    }
});
```

Both separate or together don't work. Why isn't this working. This should be basic right?! I get no console errors and `jQuery.js` as been added to the page. All other scripts work just fine.

Comment: Why dont you think it works? (Your first attempt looks fine)

Comment: Use CSS: `#ot-pr.add-product .arrow { display: block; }`

Comment: Works fine for me: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/xm3df362/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no need for JS here, you can achieve this in CSS alone:

```css
.arrow {
  display: none;    
  /* simplified CSS for the example */
}
div.add-product .arrow {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="ot-pr" class="status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry add-product">
  <span class="arrow">arrow 1</span>
</div>

<div id="ot-pr" class="status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry add-product">
  <span class="arrow">arrow 2</span>
</div>

<!-- not visible -->
<div id="ot-pr" class="status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry">
  <span class="arrow">arrow 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS only? Not sure what kind of wizardry this is... :D

Comment: @tymeJV I got a fever and the only prescription is more jQuery!

Answer (score 1):

I think no need to write javascript for this, you can manage it by CSS code only

```
.arrow {
    display: none;
    width: 0; height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #c8c8c8;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

div.add-product > span.arrow
{
   display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if($("#ot-pr").hasClass('add-product') == true){
    $(".arrow").css("display","block");
  }
  else { 
    $(".arrow").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery solution:

```js
var $arrow = $('.arrow'),
    $otPr = $('#ot-pr');

$otPr.hasClass('add-product')
  ? $arrow.show()
  : $arrow.hide();
```

```css
.arrow {
  display: block;
  /* ... */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ot-pr" class="status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry add-product">
  <span class="arrow">Some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

replace css with

```
.arrow {
    display: block;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    line-height: 0;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #c8c8c8;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

just add display:block and add height width